# WooCommerce: How to add Schema Item Condition Markup to Products?

Tags: woocommerce, schema

Google Shopping reports errors because there is no item condition associated with my products. How can I add the item condition schema into my products schema JSON?

I know I could print this HTML:

```
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
  <meta itemprop="itemCondition" itemtype="http://schema.org/OfferItemCondition" content="http://schema.org/NewCondition" />
</div>
```

But I think that it should be inside Schema.org/Product, which is inside a JSON in current WC versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to the functions.php file of your theme:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_structured_data_product_offer', 'my_woocommerce_structured_data_product_offer', 10, 2 );
function my_woocommerce_structured_data_product_offer( $markup, $product ) {    
    if ( empty( $markup[ 'itemCondition' ] ) ) {
        $markup[ 'itemCondition' ] = 'http://schema.org/NewCondition';
    }
    return $markup;
}
```

- Damaged => http://schema.org/DamagedCondition
- New => http://schema.org/NewCondition
- Refurbished => http://schema.org/RefurbishedCondition
- Used => http://schema.org/UsedCondition

Answer (score 2):

According to this:
https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/7353427?hl=en
Modify `$markup_offer` in:

```
wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\class-wc-structured-data.php
```

and add

```
'itemCondition' => 'http://schema.org/NewCondition',
```

Answer (score 0):

To apply a command dynamically, you must go through the classes defined in WooCommerce

When you use the WooCommerce plugin to set up an online store, the built-in data commands are executed automatically. To change these commands, go to the class defined for it If the variable you want to generate dynamically may not exist, set a condition for it. to set a new value write your code as follows

```
$markup['your_item']       ='your_value';
```

for example

```
if($product->get_attribute( 'pa_gtin-code' )){
   $markup['gtin13']       = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_gtin-code' );
}
```

amir taherkhani